# Enthusiastically interested in OR truly interested in?

Tags: phrase-requests

Which one is correct?

Enthusiastically interested in ...

OR

Truly interested in ...

Example: I'm enthusiastically interested in chess.

Comment: 'Interested' already conveys enthusiasm and there is no need to say 'truly' as nobody is accusing you of lying. Neither addition is necessary.

Comment: 'Extremely' would probably be the strong emphasiser of choice here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that *interested* conveys enthusiasm. But it doesn't mean this word can't be modified with an adverb.

You **can** say ***truly interested*** but you cannot say *enthusiastically interested*.

Some other common collocations are:

- Deeply interested
- Extremely interested
- Greatly interested
- Intensely interested
- Keenly interested
- Passionately interested
- Really interested
- Genuinely interested
- Seriously interested
- Specially/especially interested